# AMPL code compilation problem: is already defined

Tags: optimization, ampl

I have short task in AMPL.

There was similar question but it don't bring me the solution

It's my .mod file:

```
set MOTORS;
set FABRICS;

param work {FABRICS,MOTORS}>= 0;
param power {FABRICS}>= 0;
param price {MOTORS}>= 0;

var prod {MOTORS}>= 0;
var use {o in FABRICS} = sum {k in MOTORS} work [o,k] * prod[k];
var free {o in FABRICS} >= 0;

var income = sum {k in MOTORS} price[k]*prod[k];

maximize income;

s.t. Ogrfreepower {o in FABRICS}:  free[o]= power[o]- use[o];
```

It's my .dat file:

```
set MOTORS:= GL SL ;
set FABRICS:= montage paintshop;

    param work:  GL  SL:=
    montage   2   5 
    paintshop   3   3
        ;

    param:  power :=
    montage   150
    paintshop   180
    ;

    param:  price :=
    GL  2
    SL  3
    ;
```

It's my .run file:

```
#RESET THE AMPL ENVIROMENT

reset;

model example1.mod;

data example1.dat;

#LOAD THE MODEL

option solver './cplex';

#SOLVE
solve;

#SHOW RESULTS
display income;
```

when i try to use i console:

```
ampl: include example1.run;
```

it brings me:

```
example1.mod, line 19 (offset 314):
    income is already defined
context:  maximize  >>> income; <<<
```

what should I change to compile it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
maximize income;
```

to:

```
maximize objective_function: income;
```

AFAIK, the issue here is that AMPL treats variables and objective functions as separate entities. `maximize income` is interpreted as declaring an objective function named "income" when you already have a variable of that name, hence the "already defined" error.

Answer (score 0):

It works also when change to:

```
maximize zysk2: sum {k in SKUTERY} cena[k]*prod[k];
```

instead of:

```
var income = sum {k in SKUTERY} cena[k]*prod[k];

maximize income;
```

Comment: Yep, and if the only place where you want to use `income` is the objective function, you can remove the line where you define it as a var and just define it directly as the objective function - `maximize income: sum {k in SKUTERY} cena[k]*prod[k];`. But if you think you might want to set constraints etc. related to income, then it's easier to set it as a var and then create the OF separately.